# How to add value to an axis according how player is rotate?

Tags: unity-game-engine, vector

I want to instantiate an object 3 meters in front of my player.

To determine position, if I use something like:

```
Vector3 WhereToInstantiate = Player.transform.position; 
WhereToInstantiate.z += 3;
Instantiate(theObject, WhereToInstantiate, ...);
```

It works ONLY if my player is "looking" in the right direction, and for right direction i mean he is looking where Z is 'forward'.

So how to instantiate something based on player "look" rotation?

Comment: I really wish people google stuff before asking. You'll come up with so many results *"unity instantiate object in front of player"*...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## `Transform#forward`,`Transform#up`,`Transform#right`

These three properties return a Vector3 that is relative to the transform's facing.  e.g:

```
Vector3 WhereToInstantiate = Player.transform.position; 
WhereToInstantiate += 3 * Player.transform.forward;
Instantiate(theObject, WhereToInstantiate, ...);
```